# Check if first character of a paragraph is lowercase

Tags: c, file

I am currently working on a college project and I am in need of help because the spark has not yet happened in my brain.

The title is pretty self explanatory, I need to check if the **first character of the paragraph is lowercase**, and if it is, **count how many of them exist** in total ( this can be useful to check for errors in txt files )

Currently I have this piece of code that finds a paragraph and after that it should check whether first character is lowercase, the problem is I don't understand how can I point to the first character after the paragraph, and because of that I can't enter the `if` statement because the `new-line` is going to be 0 again. The `printf("ola\n");` is just to check if I was entering inside the condition or not, they have no other objective in the code. Thank you

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

int ch;
   FILE *fp;
   int paragraph=0;
   int newLine=0;
   int temp=0;
   fp = fopen("123.txt","r");

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){

        if(ch=='\n'){
            newLine++;
        }
        -


        if(newLine==2 && ch!='\n'){
            printf("ola\n");
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                printf("ola\n");
                temp++;
                newLine=0;
            }
        }
    }   

    printf("%d\n",temp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: try removing the else part newline=0.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input file?

Comment: @nouney " All the great teachers and reformers have recognized evil in the world, and
many of them have distinctly recognized this evil as moral evil. the doctrine of Jesus is......."

The paragraph is after "evil." and i can read them because its when \n\n happens

Comment: @aa1992 i tried removing the else part, but it still doesnt count the proper amount

Comment: Thanks for the example file. However your code can not be compiled. Please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: do you want to check the first letter lower case only when line=2?

Comment: can you please provide the input and expected output of the code in the post

Comment: I altered the code, and it should compile now

Comment: @aa1992, i want to check if the first letter of the paragraph is lowercase, so after \n\n, a new paragraph starts, and i want to see if the first character is lowercase or not

Comment: For example: 
"\n\n
today i was working on my project",  the output should be temp=1, because the paragraph started with a lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have seen this first char, you must reset newline. You also want to be sure you see 2 or more new line characters without intermediate characters:

```
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){

    while( ch=='\n' && (ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF && ch=='\n'){
        newLine= 2;
    }


    if(newLine==2 && ch!='\n'){
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            temp++;
        }
        newLine=0;
    }
}
```